# Center align inline-block div with another div floated left of it

Tags: html, css

I'm building a footer, and I have 3 parts to it: a logo floated left, a nav ul centered, and a set of social icons floated right. Whenever I float the logo left, the lis in my nav ul are being pushed to the right for no apparent reason. The ul itself is centered on the page, and there is no padding/margin on the lis so there  is no reason for them to be pushed over. Here's my code, and some screen shots.

HTML

```
        <p class="copyright footerLogo">
        OUR COMPANY LOGO</p>

        <div class="footerNavbar">


          <ul>
            <li><a href="default.asp">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="news.asp">Client Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp">Hire Us</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="socialIcons">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://facebook.com">
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-2x"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://twitter.com">
                        <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://linkedin.com">
                        <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
footer {
  text-align: center;
  height: 5em;
  background: transparent; }

footer .footerLogo {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-top: 1em; }

footer .footerNavbar {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto; }

footer .footerNavbar ul {
  padding: 0; }

footer .footerNavbar ul li {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block; }

footer .socialIcons {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 2em; }

footer .socialIcons ul li {
  display: inline-block; }
```

ul is centered:

[image: ul is centered, lis are centered]

when float left is off, lis are centered:

[image: when float left is off, lis are centered]

Comment: I edited it to show compiled code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here might be a start for you. Is this how you want?

I cleaned up the code a little and temporary added background color to each of your footer children (so much easier to see whats wrong when doing that)

```css
footer {
  height: 5em;
}

footer .footerLogo {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
}

footer .footerNavbar {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lime;
}

footer .footerNavbar ul {
  padding: 0;
}

footer .footerNavbar ul li {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block; }

footer .socialIcons {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}

footer .socialIcons ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<footer>
       <div class="copyright footerLogo">
        OUR COMPANY LOGO</div>

        <div class="footerNavbar">


          <ul>
            <li><a href="default.asp">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="news.asp">Client Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp">Hire Us</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="socialIcons">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://facebook.com">
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-2x">1</i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://twitter.com">
                        <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x">2</i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://linkedin.com">
                        <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x">3</i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Floating the navbar left? Definitely something I never thought of, but is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make a parent div that contains all 3 elements.

Elements on the left:

```
position:absolute;
left:0;
```

Elements on the right:

```
position:absolute;
right:0;
```

Relative to the parent div:

```
#parent {
position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Please add a link to jsfiddle so it be more easy to help you.
2. I think you need to use the css [clear property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clear/)